# changing root view Controller of UIWindow by using CA Transition shows black screen

Tags: ios, objective-c, uinavigationcontroller, catransition

So the issue is here, i want to change my root view controller after login functionality, for that i am using following code

```
UIWindow *win=[UIApplication sharedApplication].delegate.window;

CATransition *transition = [CATransition animation];
transition.duration = 0.5;
transition.timingFunction = [CAMediaTimingFunction functionWithName:kCAMediaTimingFunctionEaseInEaseOut];
transition.type = kCATransitionPush;
transition.subtype = kCATransitionFromRight;
[self.view.window.layer addAnimation:transition forKey:nil];
[UIView commitAnimations];
win.rootViewController= newRootController;
```

it works perfectly but i see a black screen in between transition.
Any idea how to remove, Black screen. Help Appreciated.

Comment: Why you want to change the root controller ?

Comment: after login i want to use it  from different navigation controller which use different functionality which can;t be done from same navigation controller